# data base notifications using signal R

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Am new to signalR concept. I tried to implement the Data base notification using SignalR and I successfully started the Hub. But when i call the controller using ajax function, its not giving the output. Its getting jumbed from that ajax function. this is that function,

```
function getData() 
{             
 var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');             
 $.ajax({                 
         url: ../api/values',                 
         type: 'GET',                 
         datatype: 'json',                 
         success: function (data) {                     
           if (data.length > 0) {
               $tbl.empty();                         
               $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>');                         
         var rows = [];                         
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
         {                             
          rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastExecutionDate.toString().substr(0,10) + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td></tr>');                         
          }                         
        $tbl.append(rows.join(''));                     
       }                 
    }             
  });
```

i have a doubt on passing the URL.

Pls any one solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please reformate your code such that humans can read it?

Comment: you are missing a single quote in url may be its the reason

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad - thanks. i tried that too.